# Magento API: Assigning preexisting simple products to configurable products

Tags: api, magento, product, stock, catalog

I've got a client database with a large range of stock items, which are being uploaded to Magento as simple products.

Now I need to group them up and assign them to configurable products with their size and colour being their configurable attributes.

The Magento API has a Product_Link class, with a promising looking method: catalogue-product-link.assign ([link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product_link#catalog_product_link.assign)), but I can't for the life of me figure out what arguments I need to make it work with configurable products, providing this is how assign was meant to be used.

Comment: Magento documentation is rubbish ain't it.

Comment: Oh I hear you there! I get spam from them every now and then to actually purchase user documentation. Pfft!

Comment: Yeah, I've gotten their 'suggestion' too, via Twitter. In fact, I already bought the official User Guide, which is no use for a developer. Also bought the php|architect's book, which is a good read but should be 10 times thicker.

Comment: Here is an extension that can help: http://www.johannreinke.com/en/2012/04/20/magento-api-associate-simple-products-to-configurable-or-grouped-product/ After installation, you just have to specify a key "associated_skus" to the configurable product and simple products will be associated automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the notes here helped me get this running. So I thought I'd share with you the code to add a simple product to an existing Configurable Product.

This code assumes the simple product is a valid one to add, I'm not sure what would happen if it wasn't.

```
private function _attachProductToConfigurable( $_childProduct, $_configurableProduct ) {
   $loader = Mage::getResourceModel( 'catalog/product_type_configurable' )->load( $_configurableProduct );

   $ids = $_configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds(); 
   $newids = array();
   foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
      $newids[$id] = 1;
   }

   $newids[$_childProduct->getId()] = 1;

   $loader->saveProducts( $_configurableProduct->getId(), array_keys( $newids ) );                
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this from a command line script and I fail here:
$loader = Mage::getResourceModel( 'catalog/product_type_configurable' )->load( $_configurableProduct );

(first line)
Any ideas? I'm currently investigating it and will inform in case of a result.

Comment: I updated the code by Scimon to work in recent versions of magento again: [see below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14461333/219467)

Answer (score 3):

The code from the accepted answer by Scimon does not work anymore in recent versions of magento (at least in 1.7). But fortunately, you need just a small fix to get it working again:

```
private function _attachProductToConfigurable( $_childProduct, $_configurableProduct ) {
   $loader = Mage::getResourceModel( 'catalog/product_type_configurable' )->load( $_configurableProduct, $_configurableProduct->getId() );

   $ids = $_configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds(); 
   $newids = array();
   foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
      $newids[$id] = 1;
   }

   $newids[$_childProduct->getId()] = 1;

   //$loader->saveProducts( $_configurableProduct->getid(), array_keys( $newids ) );                
   $loader->saveProducts( $_configurableProduct, array_keys( $newids ) );                
}
```

Comment: I had an excepted answer? It was a while ago, I've not done any Magento development for a year or so now so go with this.

Comment: This probably should have been an edit to the accepted answer IMHO.

Comment: @Joseph: I didn't had enough reputation to do so at the time of writing, so I did post a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on doing this right now.

So far I've found these items helpful as references:

- http://snippi.net/magento-programmatically-add-configurable-product-color-api
- http://www.omnisubsole.com/blog/2009/07/01/configurable-products-in-magento.html
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/6941/P30/

I'll post my code so far, and hopefully update it once it works..

```
// Set 'item_size' as the super attribute  # choose your own attribute!
// this is the 'choose-able' field that differenciates products
$super_attributes=array( Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
  ->loadByCode('catalog_product','item_size')
  ->getData('attribute_id')
  );  
$product_collection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

// Fetch configurable orders
$product_collection->addFieldToFilter('type_id',Array('eq'=>"configurable"));
#$product_collection->addFieldToFilter('sku',Array('eq'=>"ASMCL000002"));  

$product_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$count=0;
foreach($product_collection as $product) {
  $sku = $product->getSku();
  echo "SKU: $sku\n";

  $simple_children_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
  $simple_children_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
  $simple_children_collection->addFieldToFilter('sku',Array('like'=>$sku . "-%"));
  echo "children: ";
  foreach($simple_children_collection as $child) {
      $child_sku = $child->getSku();
      echo "$child_sku ";
      #visiblity should be 'nowhere'
  }
  echo "\n";

if (!$product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductAttributeIds()) {
  # This is a new product without the Configurable Attribue Ids set
  $product->getTypeInstance()
    ->setUsedProductAttributeIds( $super_attributes );

  //$product->setConfigurableAttributesData(array($_attributeData));
  $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true); # Not sure if this is needed.

  $product->setConfigurableProductsData(''); # Use this to add child products.

}


  $count++;

  try {
      $product->save();
      $productId = $product->getId();
      echo $product->getId() . ", $sku updated\n";
  }
  catch (Exception $e){
      echo "$sku not added\n";
      echo "exception:$e";
  }

}
echo "\nCount is $count\n";
```

Okay, this uses 'item_size' as the attribute that differentiates the "simple" products. Also, this assumes that the "configurable" parent SKU is the root of the child SKU. For example, ABC001 is the parent while ABC001-SMALL and ABC001-LARGE are the simple children.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: I don't know if you're still working on this but I think I've cracked it.

Answer (score 1):

I this is an un-educated guess, but I think what your asking for can't be done with the existing API. You will have to write your own or just got directly to the DB.

Comment: With the EAV db schema they use there is no 'just' when directly accessing the DB. The Pain!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the hack-y way that I did this straight with PHP. There are three related tables. I was using color and size as my attributes.
My parent products (configurable) don't actually exist in my catalog. They are essentially model level and then the products are the SKU level.
So LIKE 'parentproductsku%' works out for the children.

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM mage_catalog_product_entity WHERE type_id= 'configurable'";
    //Find the parent id
    $statusMessage = "Ok, found a product with a confgurable attribute";
    $result1 = $this->runQuery($query1, "query1", $statusMessage);
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) { //entering the first loop where products are configurable
        $this->parentId = $row1['entity_id'];
        $this->parentSku = $row1['sku'];

        echo "The SKU was $this->parentSku" . "<br />";

    //insert these into the link table for association
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM mage_catalog_product_entity WHERE type_id= 'simple' AND sku LIKE '" . $this->parentSku . "%';";
    // find the child ids that belong to the parent
    $statusMessage = "Found some children for $this->parentSku";
    $result2 = $this->runQuery($query2, "query2", $statusMessage);
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {//entering the second loop where SKU is like model sku
        $this->childId = $row2['entity_id'];
        $this->childSku = $row2['sku'];

        echo "Now we're working with a child SKU $this->childSku" . "<br />";

        //"REPLACE INTO catalog_product_super_attribute SET product_id='".$product->entity_id."', attribute_id='".$attribute->attribute_id."', position='".$position."'";
        $query3 = "REPLACE INTO mage_catalog_product_super_attribute  (product_id, attribute_id, position) VALUES ('" . $this->childId . "', '76', '0');";
        $message3 = "Inserted attribute for color for ID $this->childId SKU $this->childSku";
        $result3 = $this->runQuery($query3, "query3", $message3);

        $query4 = "REPLACE  INTO mage_catalog_product_super_attribute_label (product_super_attribute_id, store_id, use_default, value) VALUES (LAST_REPLACE_ID(), '0', '0', 'Color');";
        $message4 = "Inserted attribute for Color  SKU $this->childSku ID was $this->db->insert_id";
        $result4 = $this->runQuery($query4, "query4", $message4);

        $query5 = "REPLACE  INTO mage_catalog_product_super_attribute  (product_id, attribute_id, position) VALUES ('" . $this->childId . "', '529', '0');";
        $message5 = "Inserted attribute for Product Size SKU $this->childSku";
        $result5= $this->runQuery($query5, "query5", $message5);


        $query6 = "REPLACE  INTO mage_catalog_product_super_attribute_label (product_super_attribute_id, store_id, use_default, value) VALUES (LAST_REPLACE_ID(), '0', '0', 'Size');";
        $message6 = "Inserted attribute for Size SKU $this->childSku ID was $this->db->insert_id";
        $result6 = $this->runQuery($query6, "query6", $message6);

        $query7 = "REPLACE INTO mage_catalog_product_super_link (product_id, parent_id) VALUES ('" . $this->childId . "', '" . $this->parentId . "');";
        $message7 = "Inserted $this->childId and $this->parentId into the link table";
        $result7 = $this->runQuery($query7, "query7", $message7);

        $query8 = "REPLACE INTO mage_catalog_product_relation (parent_id, child_id) VALUES ('" . $this->parentId . "', '" . $this->childId . "');";
        $message8 = "Inserted $this->childId and $this->parentId into the link table";
        $result8 = $this->runQuery($query8, "query8", $message8);

        } //end while row 2 the child ID

            } //end while row 1 the parent id
```

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, this works, if all your simple products share the same price:

```
        $childProducts = $configurable->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProductIds($configurable);

        // Don't add this product if it's already there
        if(!in_array($child->getId(), $childProducts)) {    
            $childProducts[] = $child->getId();
        }


        $existingIds = $configurable->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProductAttributeIds($configurable);
        $newAttributes = array();

        foreach($configurable->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($configurable) as $attribute) {

        if(!in_array($attribute->getId(), $existingIds) && $configurable->getTypeInstance(true)->canUseAttribute($attribute)
            && $child->getAttributeText($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {

            // Init configurable attribute
            $configurableAtt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_attribute')
                ->setProductAttribute($attribute);

            // Add new attribute to array
            $newAttributes[] = array(
               'id'             => $configurableAtt->getId(),
               'label'          => $configurableAtt->getLabel(),
               'position'       => $attribute->getPosition(),
               'values'         => $configurableAtt->getPrices() ? $configurable->getPrices() : array(),
               'attribute_id'   => $attribute->getId(),
               'attribute_code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
               'frontend_label' => $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(),
            );
        }
    }

    if(!empty($newAttributes)) {

        $configurable->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
        $configurable->setConfigurableAttributesData($newAttributes);
    }
        $configurable->setConfigurableProductsData(array_flip($childProducts));
        $configurable->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

@aeno's solution did not work for me, so I refined it a bit. This has been tested using a product instantiated via the  `Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )->load()` method.

```
private function _attachProductToConfigurable( $childProduct, $configurableProduct )
{
    $childIds   = $configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();
    $childIds[] = $childProduct->getId();
    $childIds   = array_unique( $childIds );

    Mage::getResourceModel( 'catalog/product_type_configurable' )
        ->saveProducts( $configurableProduct, $childIds );
}
```